# Amazon Mechanical Turk task retrieval API

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I'm writing an app wherein the premise is that people who can't directly fund a charity out of their pocket could automatically work on Amazon AWS HITs in order to bring clean water to the 3rd world - I'd known there was an Amazon AWS API but is very unclear on how to retrieve a HIT to be worked on, rather than just consume some data about some tasks I'm trying to complete.

Is there any way to retrieve a HIT to be worked on through the AWS API or otherwise?

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only way to work on a HIT is through the mTurk website. i.e. - not via API.

There is a site that is trying to do something very similar to what you have described. http://www.sparked.com/